# Given n boolean variables, how to check if k or less of them are true only by means of propositional calculus?

Tags: boolean-logic, propositional-calculus

During my assignments for theoretical CS I stumbled over the questions how a boolean function would look, that tests if of n given boolean vars, x1 to xn, k or less variables are true.

In Java this would be fairly simple :

```
public boolean k_or_less_true(boolean[] x , int k) {

   int num_true = 0;
   int n = boolean.size;
   for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
       if(x[i]){num_true++;}
   }

   return num_true <= k;
}
```

The problem now is to find a formula by means of propositional calculus dependent on n and k, that returns true only and only if k or less  of the n given are true.

To give an example, if we let k = 1, the formula corresponds to the NAND-function :

(x1 , x2)<sup><=1</sup>  =  NOT(x1 AND x2)

(x1 , x2 , x3)<sup><=1</sup> = NOT( (NOT(x1 AND x2)) AND x3) 
.
.
.

So far the question is, how the formula changes if k increases...

Also a pretty obvious connection is :

(x1, x2, ..., xn)<sup><=k</sup> = (x1, ..., xn)<sup>=k</sup> OR (x1, ..., xn)<sup>=k-1</sup> OR ... OR (x1, ..., xn)<sup><=1</sup>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a mathematics question, not a computer programming question. You already have the computer program.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward formula for this is the following:

```
f(S) = not [ OR(for T in S^(k+1)) [ AND(for t in T) t ] ]
```

In the above:

- OR is a repeated logical OR of all terms computed from a set
- S^(k+1) is the set of all (k+1)-subsets of S
- AND is a repeated logical AND of all terms computed from a set

The idea is this:

> It is the case that k or fewer are true if and only if it is not the case that at least k+1 are true. At least k+1 are true if and only if some subset of exactly k+1 are all true.